# Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling in production

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, scalability

I have realized that I have to make Image from EBS Volume everytime when I change my code

and following autoscaling configuration everytime (this is really bad).

I have heard that some people try to load their newest code from github or some similar sort of doing.

So that they can let server to have newest code automatically without making new image every single time.

I already have a private github.

Is it a only way to solve Auto-Scaling code management ?

If so, how can I configure this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user-data scripts, which work on a lot of public images including Amazon's. You could have it download puppet manifests/templates/files and run directly. Search for master less puppet.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention them, even though I invented "user-data scripts" :-) Note, however, that this approach may take longer to bring the instance fully up to spec, which is often a concern with auto scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configure your AMI so that the instance loads the latest software and configuration on first boot before it is put into service in the auto scaling group.

How to set up a startup script may depend on the specific os and version you are running.

Comment: I'm running with Ubuntu 11.04 natty